# I am trying to add Contextmenu option. but am getting "TheThe Appx package's manifest is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)

Tags: manifest

trying to enable contextmenu options in msix package but its throwing error.

```
<desktop9:Extension Category="windows.fileExplorerClassicContextMenuHandler">
    <desktop9:FileExplorerClassicContextMenuHandler>
        <desktop9:ExtensionHandler Type="*" Clsid="<GUID-for-the-com-server>" />
        <desktop9:ExtensionHandler Type=".txt" Clsid="<GUID-for-the-com-server>" />
        <desktop9:ExtensionHandler Type="Directory" Clsid="<GUID-for-the-com-server>" />
    </desktop9:FileExplorerClassicContextMenuHandler>
</desktop9:Extension>

<desktop9:Extension Category="windows.fileExplorerClassicDragDropContextMenuHandler">
    <desktop9:FileExplorerClassicDragDropContextMenuHandler>
        <desktop9:ExtensionHandler Type="Directory" Clsid="<GUID-for-the-com-server>" />
        <desktop9:ExtensionHandler Type="Drive" Clsid="<GUID-for-the-com-server>" />
    </desktop9:FileExplorerClassicDragDropContextMenuHandler>
</desktop9:Extension>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.